# Repdigit sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Is there a formula to determine the probability of a sequence of repdigits in a longer sequence of random numbers?

The Feynman point in $\pi$, for example, occurring within the first $1{,}000$ decimal digits of $\pi$. But for any repdigits and not just $9$'s.

The probability of $6$ $9$'s occurring within the first $1000$ digits (assuming $\pi$ is random) is $0.0009995$ according to either of these formulae:

$$P = 1 - (1 - (0.1)^d)^N$$
$$P = 1 - e^{-N(0.1)^d}$$

but I'd really like to know the formula for repdigits in general.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $d$ is $6$, the number of $9$s you want, and $N$ is $1000$, the length of the string.  Please define your variables.  In that case the first is almost correct and the second is a (rather accurate) approximation to the first.  Do you see how the first is derived?  That is the key.  The exponent $N$ is not quite correct because the string can't start in the last few positions.

If the probability of a string of $9$s is small, the probability of a string of any digit is $10$ times higher. If it is not small, you double count the chance of two different strings.  You can get very close by decreasing $d$ by $1$, because you are looking for a string of specifically $d-1$ digits that match the specific previous digit.  The really right way is to make a Markov chain where each state is the length of the terminal string.